# What resources are there for students to compute on a data stream?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, education, streaming-algorithm

I teach a randomized algorithms course, and many of the cool applications are to streaming computation. I can have students implement these algorithms in Python or C++, but I feel it would be much cooler to have them do it in a streaming environment. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, IBM Streams and Google's BigQuery are prohibitively expensive. Are there free tools for educational use? You would think that companies would want students to learn these things in college, rather than constantly having to train them on the job.

Comment: Tool requests are generally offtopic here; migrate to [softwarerecs.SE]?

Comment: Thanks for the retag. I had not found "education". Also, good to learn about the software SE, which I didn't know about. Still, what I'd really like is feedback from cs professors about what they have done in their classes related to randomized algorithms and streaming. In math and stats there are listservs and forums to discuss and share pedagogical techniques. I don't know of any such thing in CS, but I really wish there was an analogue.

Comment: @DavidWhite You may be interested in the new SE, CS Educators: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/  This would definitely be on topic there